# QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr) not calling

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcpserver

I'm trying to make client and server using [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) and [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html).

So, what happens to server.

1. I run the server, it starts listening (successfully [checked by myself])
2. I run client, enter `127.0.0.1` for `IP address` and `30000` for `port`
3. Client says that connection estabilished
4. Server doesn't do anything, just keep waiting

Parts of my program:

```
//server-work.h
#ifndef SERVERWORK_H
#define SERVERWORK_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include "lssclient.h"
class LSSClient;

class LTcpServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    class LTWorkWithClients : public QThread
    {
        //Q_OBJECT
    public:
        LTcpServer* server;
        LTWorkWithClients(QObject* parent = 0, LTcpServer *server = 0):
            QThread(parent)
        {
            this->server = server;
        }

    protected:
        void run() {
            qDebug() << "started";
            server->workWithIncomingConnection();
        }
    };

    QSqlDatabase db; // clients in database

    LTWorkWithClients* t_workWithClients;
    QQueue<quintptr> clientsToBeAttached;
    QList<LSSClient*> clients;

    LResult workWithIncomingConnection  ();

    LResult serverInit          ();
    LResult createDatabase      ();

    static QTextStream& qStdout ();

    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

protected:

private:

};

#endif // SERVERWORK_H
```

I know that this nested thread class is strongly wrong way to do this thing, but i don't have much time to do it correctly

```
// server-work.cpp [PART]
LResult LTcpServer::serverInit()
{
    checkError;
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("serverDB");

    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Error opening database...";
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
        return LVError;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Database successfully opened";
    }
    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 30000)){
        qDebug() << "Error starting listening...";
        return LVError;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Start listening successfully";
    }
    t_workWithClients = new LTWorkWithClients(this, this);
    t_workWithClients->start();
    return LVSuccess;
}

void LTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " new connection";
    clientsToBeAttached.enqueue(socketDescriptor);
    qDebug() << "here1";
}

LResult LTcpServer::workWithIncomingConnection()
{
    bool toExit = false;
    while (!toExit) {
        checkError;
        qDebug() << "1";
        if (clientsToBeAttached.length() != 0) {
            quintptr eachClientDescriptor = clientsToBeAttached.dequeue();
            qDebug() << "2";
            LSSClient* client = new LSSClient(this);
            client->server = this;
            client->socket->setSocketDescriptor(eachClientDescriptor);
            qDebug() << "3";
            client->registered = false;
            client->server = this;
            qDebug() << client->socket->localAddress();
            connect(client->socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), client, SLOT(onSokReadyRead()));
            connect(client->socket, SIGNAL(connected()), client, SLOT(onSokConnected()));
            connect(client->socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), client, SLOT(onSokDisconnected()));
            connect(client->socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),client, SLOT(onSokDisplayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
            clients.append(client);
        }
        usleep(1000000);
    }
    return LVSuccess;
}
```

So, server just keep writing 1 (nothing more) every second, but client says that it is connected to the server.

Comment: I'd say that first you should get it working without any extra threads. Only when it works in the main thread, you should move the object to a `QThread` (you don't need to derive from `QThread`).

Comment: I can see `serverInit` is where you are creating the thread, you are not calling it anywhere here.

Comment: if you want to have a separate thread to handle your connections, you are really doing wrong. here are some issues with your current design: 1) `clientsToBeAttached`, `server` are used in both threads without any synchronization mechanism. 2) you are polling every 1 second to check if there are any new connected clients in the queue. This is a typical example of a producer/consumer problem. take a look at how this is done in Qt [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-waitconditions-example.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-semaphores-example.html).

Comment: but it would be better for you to read the [Qt Threaded Fortune Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html) to avoid threading problems. Also, are you sure you want to go multithreaded? why not run everything in your GUI thread?

Comment: The problem is that incomingConnecion not firing (no qdebug message). I can't see sence of doing threads fight way before I understand why incomingConnecion not firing... Also, i tried to use newConnection(without passing to other thread), it also wasn't firing ... thanks for eз links, but i already have seen fortune example @Mike

Comment: @Kuba Ober, look onto my preivious comment

Comment: @Mike it's planed as big project starting from learning some Qt

Answer (score 0):

This structure might help...

in your ltcpserver.h file:

```
class LTcpServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LTcpServer(QObject * parent = 0);
    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
private:
    QThread *myThread;
};
```

and in your ltcpserver.cpp:

```
LTcpServer::LTcpServer(QObject * parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    if(this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,30000))
    {
        qDebug() << "server started...";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "server could not be started...";
    }
    myThread = new QThread();
    myThread->start();
}

void LTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    LSSClient * yourClient = new LSSClient(socketDescriptor);
    yourClient->moveToThread(myThread);
    clients->append(yourClient);
}
```

and in your lssclient.h

```
class LSSClient: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LSSClient(qintptr socketDescriptor,QObject * parent = 0);
private:
    void setupSocket(qintptr socketDescriptor);
    QTcpSocket * socket;
public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();
};
```

and in your lssclient.cpp

```
LSSClient::LSSClient(qintptr socketDescriptor,QObject * parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    setupSocket(qintptr socketDescriptor);
}

void LSSClient::setupSocket(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(sDescriptor);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()));
}

void LSSClient::readyRead()
{
    // do whatever you want here with incoming data
}

void LSSClient::disconnected()
{
    // do what happens to client when disconnected
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? The incomingConnecion signature is just like mine...

Comment: yup... you're using the thread badly... change was done in threading

Comment: But will it help me?.. is it a real reason why incomingConnecion not firing?

Comment: Anyways, i will try your structure.. what does QThread mean? Thread that does nothing? Or just example?

Comment: as I understood you want to deal with clients in another thread (am i right?)

Comment: so we create a QThread and move clients that connect to it "yourClient->moveToThread(myThread);" any slots that these clients want to call it will be run in that particular thread

Comment: yes, you're right. But it's not an error i wanted you to help me with... (anyways, thanks)... But my error is that QTcpServer::incomingConnection(quintptr) not firing AT ALL (no qDebug message, look onto my code) [sorry for my English]

Comment: what should i do when i realised that that was blocking while loop in main.cpp program. i should put my stupid unusable answer on stupid problem or ?

Comment: you're using a while loop which is not a great way to do your multiple threaded programming...

Comment: what should i do with this question? answer it or ?

Comment: @ЛеонидМащенко , So, your problem was that there was no event loop running in your main thread?

Comment: yeah, you're right. that was cause my server is daemonic, and i have the server-bridge app to connect to server, work on it, and safely disconnect